# Windows User Variable for XAMPP Document Root

Tags: windows, xampp

I have to use XAMPP on Windows 10 Pro x64 for two different users and none of them is able to see the other users files.

Therefore i want to change the XAMPP document root for something dynamic like that:

```
C:\users\%USERNAME%\documents\workspace
```

I tried it with `%USERNAME%` and `$USER` but it didnt worked - i was not able to start apache.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/504440/using-setenv-in-apache-windows-documentroot suggest that the correct syntax would be ${username}

Comment: @Richard thank you! That syntax did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Richard - his suggestion was the right one. The correct syntax is `${username}`